# Performance of my multithreaded application does not change when I change CPU Affinity

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore

I have a C# executable that stress tests a web server by throwing thousands of requests asynchronously.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Int32.Parse(TextThreads.Text); i++)
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(WorkerThreadProc);
            workerThread.Start();
        }
```

The WorkerThreadProc is a method that simply sends the request to the URL.

As I increase the number of threads, the elapsed time reduces, which is normal.

When I change the Affinity of the executable using the Windows Task Manager, say from All CPUs to one CPU, to two CPUs, I seem to always be getting the same results as far as the amount of time it takes when I change the number of threads.

Is it the code that is not taking advantage of the multi-core computer? Or is this what I should be expecting?

Comment: Is the load CPU bound?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I right-clicked the .exe and selected the Affinity to all CPUs (4), one CPU, and then two CPUS, as I explained above. I ran one test per each of these scenarios. Seem to be getting the same results.